# Логика калькулятора

Tags: jquery

Есть небольшая табличка товаров с ценами и селектом (выбор кол-во товаров).

Хотелось бы чтобы js-ом при загрузке страницы, в поле общая сумма выводить эту самую общую сумму и в дальнейшем пересчитывать в зависимости от кол-во выбранного товара.

Код:

```js
var total = 0;

//При загрузке стр. отобразить общую сумму присутствующих товаров
$('.price').each(function(){
  var val = parseInt($(this).html());

  total += val;
  
  resPr();
});

// Изменение количества товара
$( ".select" ).selectmenu({
  change: function( event, data ) {
    var         
        tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        curPrice = tr.find('.price'),
        curPriceVal = parseInt(curPrice.data('price')),
        table = tr.closest('table');


    var val = curPriceVal*data.item.value;
    curPrice.html((val));

    total += val;     // Отсет от total после загрузки стр. А нужен пересчет. ?*

    resPr();

  }
});

// Удалить ячейку
$('.delete').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var item = $(this).closest('tr'),
      valPr = item.find('.price'),
      val = parseInt(valPr.html());



  total -= val;
  item.remove();

  resPr();
});


// Запись результата
function resPr(){
  var resPrice = $('.res');

  resPrice.each(function(){
    var res = $(this);

    res.html(total);
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  padding: .5rem;;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.res {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="price" data-price="1200">1200</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="count" class="select">
          <option selected="selected">1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="price" data-price="800">800</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="count" class="select">
          <option selected="selected">1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        res: <span class="res">0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**Но** не получается настроить этот пересчет суммы.

**Вопрос:** как правильно настроить **пересчет** общей стоимости товара при выборе кол-ва в `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует вычислять сумму ДО изменения и затем отнимать эту сумму и прибавлять новую. Для этого используем метод [open](https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-open).

```js
var total = 0;
var el_last_sum = 0; //сумма ДО изменения количества

//При загрузке стр. отобразить общую сумму присутствующих товаров
$('.price').each(function() {
  var val = parseInt($(this).html());
  total += val;

  resPr();
});

// Изменение количества товара
$(".select").selectmenu({
  open: function(event, ui) {
    var
      tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
      curPrice = tr.find('.price'),
      curPriceVal = parseInt(curPrice.data('price'));

    el_last_sum = curPriceVal * $(this).val(); //получаем сумму по текущей строке

  },
  change: function(event, data) {
    var
      tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
      curPrice = tr.find('.price'),
      curPriceVal = parseInt(curPrice.data('price')),
      table = tr.closest('table');

    var val = curPriceVal * data.item.value;
    curPrice.html((val));

    total = total - el_last_sum + val; // Отсет от total после загрузки стр. А нужен пересчет. ?*

    resPr();

  }
});

// Удалить ячейку
$('.delete').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var item = $(this).closest('tr'),
    valPr = item.find('.price'),
    val = parseInt(valPr.html());

  total -= val;
  item.remove();

  resPr();
});


// Запись результата
function resPr() {
  var resPrice = $('.res');

  resPrice.each(function() {
    var res = $(this);

    res.html(total);
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  padding: .5rem;
  ;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.res {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="price" data-price="1200">1200</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="count" class="select">
          <option selected="selected">1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="price" data-price="800">800</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="count" class="select">
          <option selected="selected">1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      res: <span class="res">0</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Здорово! Спасибо! Вот это то что нужно `total = total - el_last_sum + val;`

Comment: @Elena убрали лишнюю строку из кода в методе `open` и возможно в Вашем коде лишняя строка `table = tr.closest('table');` в методе `change` (во всяком случае в приведенном Вами коде `table` в js дальше нигде не используется).

Answer (score 2):

Есть два пути:
  Первый: При выборе в select бежишь по всем "price" и "count" и считаешь общую сумму с помощью:

```
var Summ = 0;    
$("table tr").each(function(){
            Summ += Number($(this).find('.price').text()) * Number($(this).find('select[name="count"]').val())
        })
```

И второй: Отслеживаешь какой был выбран, уменьшаешь на это число сумму и прибавляешь новое, но тогда надо отказаться от select в сторону input и событие keypress.

Comment: Как тогда из jquery ui selectmenu взять `$(this).find('select[name="count"]').val()` ?

Comment: Не понял, это относится ко второму варианту или к первому?

Comment: Я использую select jquery ui, а  в вашем решении есть `Number($(this).find('select[name="count"]').val())` но таким способом не получить значения из селекта ui ...

Comment: Попробуй просто select написать, в чем проблема, тут же по сути идея.

Comment: За суть, да! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Только что проверил, то что я написал у меня работает.

Comment: Странно, у меня undefined (возможно не правильно воспользовалась)