# Логика калькулятора, пересчет общей суммы при клике

Tags: jquery

В [продолжение вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632132/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) о работе калькулятора.

Как применить пересчет общей суммы товаров при клике (`+` \ `-`), а не выборе `select`?

**Код:**

```js
// Calculation
var total = 0;
var el_last_sum = 0; //сумма ДО изменения количества


//При загрузке стр. отображать общую цену.
$('.price>i').each(function(){
   var val = parseInt($(this).html()),
       totalSumWrap = $('#total');

   total += val;
   totalSumWrap.html(total);
});


function calculation(){

  $('.btn__calc').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var 
    $this      = $(this),
        fieldName  = $this.attr('data-field'),
        type       = $this.attr('data-type'),
        input      = $("input[name='"+fieldName+"']"),
        currentVal = parseInt(input.val()),
        tr         = $this.closest('tr'),
        sum        = tr.find('.price>i'),
        startSum   = parseInt(tr.find('.price').data('price')),
        totalSumWrap = $('#total'),
        counter;
    

    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      if(type == 'minus') {
        var minValue = parseInt(input.attr('min'));
        if(!minValue) minValue = 1;
        if(currentVal > minValue) {
          input.val(currentVal - 1).change();

          counter = input.val();
          sum.html(counter*startSum);

          totalSumWrap.html(parseInt(sum.html()));

          console.log(total);

        }

        if(parseInt(input.val()) == minValue) {
          $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }

      } else if(type == 'plus') {
        var maxValue = parseInt(input.attr('max'));
        if(!maxValue) maxValue = 9999999999999;

        if(currentVal < maxValue) {
          input.val(currentVal + 1).change();

          counter = input.val();
          
          var val = counter*startSum;
          sum.html(val);

          totalSumWrap.html(parseInt(sum.html()));                     


          
          //total = total - el_last_sum + val; //Как применить el_last_sum и обновление общей суммы?
          console.log(total);

        }

        if(parseInt(input.val()) == maxValue) {
          $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }

      }
    } else {
      input.val(0);
    }
  });
}

calculation();
```

```css
#total {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price i{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="price" data-price="4000">
        <i>4000</i> руб/шт
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="calculation">
        <button class="btn__calc calc__minus" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">-</button>
        <label for="calc-1" class="label__calc">
          <input type="text" name="quant[1]" id="calc-1" class="input_calc" value="1" min="1" max="10">
          <!-- <span>шт.</span> -->
        </label>
        <button class="btn__calc calc__plus" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">+</button>       
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="price" data-price="2000">
        <i>2000</i> руб/шт
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="calculation">
        <button class="btn__calc calc__minus" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[2]">-</button>
        <label for="calc-2" class="label__calc">
          <input type="text" name="quant[2]" id="calc-2" class="input_calc" value="1" min="1" max="10">
          <!-- <span>шт.</span> -->
        </label>
        <button class="btn__calc calc__plus" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[2]">+</button>       
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
  <div id="total"></div>
```

Общая сумма сейчас пересчитывается только для одного поля, а нужно чтобы для всех (например, если первого выбрать 2 шт., то 4000*2 = 8000 + 2000 (второго поля) = 10 000 и т.д.).

Comment: а в чем принципиальное отличие обработчика кнопки от обработчика select?

Comment: @Grundy, там в `open` вычисляется `el_last_sum = curPriceVal * $(this).val(); //получаем сумму по текущей строке` и при изменении `change` уже `total = total - el_last_sum + val; // Отсчет от total после загрузки стр.`  Разница в том, что я не могу это теперь к клику применить )

Comment: и еще непонятно зачем вызывать: _input.val(currentVal - 1).change();_ если нет навешивания обработчика

Comment: А почему просто не пробежать по всем суммам и не сложить их?

Comment: @Grundy, так ? https://jsbin.com/roxotiq/edit?js,console,output тоже не то

Comment: Почти. У тебя какая-то странная переменная total. Перед циклом ее надо обнулять, а не просто добавлять к ней значения.

Comment: @Grundy, кажется заработало))) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная ошибка в строке:

```
totalSumWrap.html(parseInt(sum.html()));
```

Вместо использования формулы указанной в прошлом вопросе, тут общая цена замещается ценой элемента, который поменяли.

<sub>`parseInt` в этом случае тоже не нужен, потому что после него ты опять к строке все приводишь, и если его убрать - ничего не поменяется.</sub>

Формула довольно проста:

1. Взять текущее *общее* значение
2. вычесть из него старое значение для элемента
3. добавить в него новое значение

Текущее значение получить просто: `totalSumWrap.html()`
Старое значение элемента, также имеется: `sum.html()`
Новое значение: `counter*startSum`

Таким образом код может принять следующий вид:

```js
// Calculation
var total = 0;
var el_last_sum = 0; //сумма ДО изменения количества

function updateValues(input, sum, startSum, totalSumWrap) {
  var counter = input.val();
  var total = parseInt(totalSumWrap.html());
  var oldSum = parseInt(sum.html());
  var newSum = counter * startSum;
  sum.html(newSum);
  totalSumWrap.html(total - oldSum + newSum);
}
//При загрузке стр. отображать общую цену.
$('.price>i').each(function() {
  var val = parseInt($(this).html()),
    totalSumWrap = $('#total');

  total += val;
  totalSumWrap.html(total);
});

function calculation() {
  $('.btn__calc').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var
      $this = $(this),
      fieldName = $this.attr('data-field'),
      type = $this.attr('data-type'),
      input = $("input[name='" + fieldName + "']"),
      currentVal = parseInt(input.val()),
      tr = $this.closest('tr'),
      sum = tr.find('.price>i'),
      startSum = parseInt(tr.find('.price').data('price')),
      totalSumWrap = $('#total'),
      counter;


    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      if (type == 'minus') {
        var minValue = parseInt(input.attr('min'));
        if (!minValue) minValue = 1;
        if (currentVal > minValue) {
          input.val(currentVal - 1);
          updateValues(input, sum, startSum, totalSumWrap)
        }

        if (parseInt(input.val()) == minValue) {
          $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }

      } else if (type == 'plus') {
        var maxValue = parseInt(input.attr('max'));
        if (!maxValue) maxValue = 9999999999999;

        if (currentVal < maxValue) {
          input.val(currentVal + 1);
          updateValues(input, sum, startSum, totalSumWrap)
        }

        if (parseInt(input.val()) == maxValue) {
          $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }

      }
    } else {
      input.val(0);
    }
  });
}

calculation();
```

```css
#total {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price i {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="price" data-price="4000">
        <i>4000</i> руб/шт
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="calculation">
        <button class="btn__calc calc__minus" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">-</button>
        <label for="calc-1" class="label__calc">
          <input type="text" name="quant[1]" id="calc-1" class="input_calc" value="1" min="1" max="10">
          <!-- <span>шт.</span> -->
        </label>
        <button class="btn__calc calc__plus" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">+</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="price" data-price="2000">
        <i>2000</i> руб/шт
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="calculation">
        <button class="btn__calc calc__minus" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[2]">-</button>
        <label for="calc-2" class="label__calc">
          <input type="text" name="quant[2]" id="calc-2" class="input_calc" value="1" min="1" max="10">
          <!-- <span>шт.</span> -->
        </label>
        <button class="btn__calc calc__plus" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[2]">+</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="total"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решила, обнулением `total` и пересчетом суммы `each()`.

> У тебя какая-то странная переменная total. Перед циклом ее надо
>   обнулять, а не просто добавлять к ней значения. – Grundy 1 час назад

**Код:**

```js
// Calculation
var total = 0;


//При загрузке стр. отображать общую цену.
$('.price>i').each(function(){
  var val = parseInt($(this).html()),
      totalSumWrap = $('#total');

  total += val;
  totalSumWrap.html(total);
});


function calculation(){

  $('.btn__calc').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var 
    $this      = $(this),
        fieldName  = $this.attr('data-field'),
        type       = $this.attr('data-type'),
        input      = $("input[name='"+fieldName+"']"),
        currentVal = parseInt(input.val()),
        tr         = $this.closest('tr'),
        sum        = tr.find('.price>i'),
        startSum   = parseInt(tr.find('.price').data('price')),
        totalSumWrap = $('#total'),
        counter;
    

    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      if(type == 'minus') {
        var minValue = parseInt(input.attr('min'));
        if(!minValue) minValue = 1;
        if(currentVal > minValue) {
          input.val(currentVal - 1).change();

          counter = input.val();
          sum.html(counter*startSum);

          totalSumWrap.html(parseInt(sum.html()));

          //console.log(total);

        }

        if(parseInt(input.val()) == minValue) {
          $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }

      } else if(type == 'plus') {
        var maxValue = parseInt(input.attr('max'));
        if(!maxValue) maxValue = 9999999999999;

        if(currentVal < maxValue) {
          input.val(currentVal + 1).change();

          counter = input.val();
          
          var val = counter*startSum;
          sum.html(val);

          totalSumWrap.html(parseInt(sum.html()));                     


          
          //total += val; //Как применить el_last_sum и обновление общей суммы?
          //console.log(total);

        }

        if(parseInt(input.val()) == maxValue) {
          $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }

      }
    } else {
      input.val(0);
    }
    
    total = 0;
    
    
    $('.price>i').each(function(){
      var val = parseInt($(this).html()),
      totalSumWrap = $('#total');

      total += val;
      totalSumWrap.html(total);
      
      console.log(total);
    });
    
  });
}

calculation();

$('.delete').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var item = $(this).closest('tr'),
      price = item.find('.price>i').html(),
      totalSumWrap = $('#total');
  
  item.remove();
  
  
  total -= price;
  
  totalSumWrap.html(total);
  
});
```

```css
#total {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price i{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

  
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="price" data-price="4000">
        <i>4000</i> руб/шт
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="calculation">
        <button class="btn__calc calc__minus" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">-</button>
        <label for="calc-1" class="label__calc">
          <input type="text" name="quant[1]" id="calc-1" class="input_calc" value="1" min="1" max="10">
          <!-- <span>шт.</span> -->
        </label>
        <button class="btn__calc calc__plus" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">+</button>       
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="price" data-price="2000">
        <i>2000</i> руб/шт
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="calculation">
        <button class="btn__calc calc__minus" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[2]">-</button>
        <label for="calc-2" class="label__calc">
          <input type="text" name="quant[2]" id="calc-2" class="input_calc" value="1" min="1" max="10">
          <!-- <span>шт.</span> -->
        </label>
        <button class="btn__calc calc__plus" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[2]">+</button>       
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
  <div id="total"></div>
```